# How can you navigate to a specific screen in flutter with the bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bottom navbar in my flutter application and it has 3 screens and one of the screens of the bottom navbar has a button which navigates to a whole new page which is not one of the screens in the bottom navbar. And in the new page I want to have a back button which navigates you back to the specific page which lead you to the whole new page. I used `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(TabsScreen.routeName)` but it just took me to the first page of the bottom navbar.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: You can make a list of screens/widgets and define ```currentIndex:``` property inside your ```BottomNavigationBar``` and change it with ```OnTap``` property to show different screens in your list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add a currentIndex argument to your navigator class. You can navigate to a specific page using:

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              NavigationEngine(currentIndex: // index of the page you want to go,),
        ),
      ),
```

Your BottomNavigationBar class should look like this:

```
class NavigationEngine extends StatefulWidget {
  final int currentIndex;
  const NavigationEngine({Key key, @required this.currentIndex})
      : super(key: key);

@override
_NavigationEngineState createState() => _NavigationEngineState();
}

class _NavigationEngineState extends State<NavigationEngine> {
  int _currentIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentIndex = widget.currentIndex;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        elevation: 0,
        items: [
          // your navigation bar items
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "home"),
        ],
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentIndex,
        children: [
          // your navigation pages
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in this     items: [
          // your navigation bar items
        ], I am confused what you mean by navbar items

Comment: Just edit my answer with an example. Add a BottomNavigationBarItem() to create a navigation tab. It is used for displaying an icon and a label. Of course the number of items should be the same as the navigation pages.